# Setting up task predecessors correctly

Tags: waterfall

Using Open Project (or MS Project, i suppose), in the following example:

[image]

- does #13 depend on #7?
- does #14 depend on #7?
- does #13 depend on #12?
- does #14 depend on #12?

Or does it matter at all? Please assume `waterfall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7,9,13, & 15 are "Summary Tasks", or "Roll-Up" views. They're combinations of other tasks (9 is the sum of 10,11,12, and 7 is the sum of 8,10,11,12), not tasks in and of themselves. So no, they would not have predecessors.

12 is a task, and can have a predecessor.

So for your questions -

1. No. 14 would follow (depend) 8. Both 13 and 7 are summary tasks.
2. No. 14 would follow 8. No 13 is a summary task.
3. No. 14 would follow 12. 13 is a summary task.
4. Yes. See above.

Answer (score 0):

And to add to Trevor's explanation, you have both hard predecessors and soft predecessors.  A task can have a finish start relationship because the first task MUST finish before the second begins.  That is hard logic.  But you can also have the same logic based on a resource constraint or other scheduling logic.  That would be considered soft logic.

Every leaf level task or package should have a predecessor-successor relationship somewhere in the schedule.  No task should be orphaned.  That way, your ability to manage a critical path or two will not be compromised.